# Call js function from Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to call js function which is placed in file script.js

If my code is waiting for the document will be ready and then browser tries to call function **makeFastOrder()** I receive error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: makeFastOrder is not defined
```

If I do not wrap my function on +function($){ ... makeFastOrder(){} ... }(jQuery); all is OK.

How can I call the wrapped function correct?

Call function from Contact Form 7:

```
on_sent_ok: "makeFastOrder();"
```

Code which doesn't work correct:

```
+function($){
    function makeFastOrder()
    {
        console.log( 123 );
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this too. Then I disabled "All in One SEO Pack". Then it worked.

Comment: I think this problem is some about local and global scope. But I'm not sure. Also I'm not have "All in One SEO Pack"

Comment: Ya may be, Sometime JS conflict may be there